# Relation between the commutator of commutators in Dirac algebra

Tags: general-relativity, group-theory, lie-algebra, qft-in-curved-spacetime, clifford-algebra

[image]

In an attemption to obtain the curvature tensor related to the spin connection of the fermionic fields I came across this expression with the commutator of the gamma matrices commutators. My question is how to obtain the following identity
$$
\omega^{ab}_\mu\omega^{cd}_\nu(\sigma_{ab}\sigma_{cd}-\sigma_{cd}\sigma_{ab}) =(\omega^{ac}_\mu{\omega_{\nu c}}^b-\omega^{ac}_\nu{\omega_{\mu c}}^b)\sigma_{ab}\ ,
$$
where $\omega^{ab}_\mu$ stands for the spin connection. And
$$
\sigma^{ab}\equiv \frac{i}{2}[\gamma^a,\gamma^b]\ ,
$$
with $\gamma_a$ the Dirac gamma matrices satisfying the anti-commutation relation
$$
\{\gamma^a,\gamma^b\}=2\eta^{ab}\ ,
$$
where $\eta^{ab}$ are the components of the Minkowski spacetime metric.

I'm quite well familiarized with the precedure to rewrite the permutatation of the gamma matrices but I have no succeed in obtainning a way to rewrite $\sigma_{ab}$  to the right side. Do you know any way to obtain this relation?

Comment: Hint - what algebra do the sigma satisfy

Comment: What I have is the definition of the sigma in terms of the commutator of Dirac matrices. If by "what algebra" you are asking for the commutation relation satisfied by the sigma, that's exactly what I'm asking for as well.

Comment: OK - well you could work out the commits tor of two sigma from their definition, or look it up, as the sigmas give you a representation of the Lorentz group (more precisely they are generators, so their commutators satisfy the appropriate Lie algebra)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I hope you recognize that the term you are trying to simplify is actually a commutator $$[\sigma_{ab},\sigma_{cd}]=\sigma_{ab}\sigma_{cd}-\sigma_{cd}\sigma_{ab}\tag{1}.$$

Second, you must recall that the $\sigma^{ab}$ defined as in your equation $$\sigma^{ab}=\dfrac{i}{2}[\gamma^a,\gamma^b]\tag{2}$$
form a representation of the Lorentz algebra. In a sense this is exactly how the spinor representations of the Lorentz group are constructed: one first looks for matrices obeying the Clifford algebra $\{\gamma^a,\gamma^b\}=2\eta^{ab}$ and then construct matrices $\sigma^{ab}$ like done in (2). The space of column vectors on which such matrices acts in the end furnish the spinor representation.

Now, *by definition*, since $\sigma^{ab}$ represents the Lorentz algebra, it must obey $$[\sigma_{ab},\sigma_{cd}]=\frac{1}{2} ( \eta_{bc}\sigma_{ad} -\eta_{ac}\sigma_{bd} -\eta_{da}\sigma_{cb} +\eta_{db}\sigma_{ca} ).\tag{3}$$

Therefore you are lead to evaluate \begin{eqnarray}\omega_\mu^{ab}\omega_{\nu}^{cd}[\sigma_{ab},\sigma_{cd}]&=&\frac{\omega_\mu^{ab}\omega_{\nu}^{cd}}{2} ( \eta_{bc}\sigma_{ad} -\eta_{ac}\sigma_{bd} -\eta_{da}\sigma_{cb} +\eta_{db}\sigma_{ca} )\\ &=&\frac{1}{2} \left( (\omega_\mu)^{ac}(\omega_\nu)_{c}^{\phantom{c}b} -(\omega_\mu)^{ca}(\omega_\nu)_c^{\phantom{c}b} -(\omega_\mu)_{c}^{\phantom{c}b} \omega_\nu^{ac} +(\omega_\mu)^{b}_{\phantom{b}c}\omega_\nu^{ac} \right)\sigma_{ab}\\ &=&\left( (\omega_\mu)^{ac}(\omega_\nu)_{c}^{\phantom{c}b} -(\omega_\nu)^{ac}(\omega_\mu)_c^{\phantom{c}b}\right)\sigma_{ab}\tag{4}\end{eqnarray}
where from the first line to the second you use the metric to contract the flat indices of the $\omega_\mu^{ab}$, $\omega_{\nu}^{cd}$ and manipulate the indices in order to factor a $\sigma_{ab}$, and from the second line to the third you use anti-symmetry $\omega_\mu^{ab}=-\omega_{\mu}^{ba}$ to combine the terms.

Answer (score 0):

Before going on reading, you *must* work out the fundamental identity for the Lorentz algebra representation embedded in the Clifford one,
$$
[ \sigma^{ab},  \sigma^{cd} ]= \tfrac{1}{2} ( \eta^{bc}\sigma^{ad} -\eta^{ac}\sigma^{bd} -\eta^{da}\sigma^{cb} +\eta^{db}\sigma^{ca} ).  
$$
Check all antisymmetries  *[[ab], [cd]]*.